# Limit of function with sine in the numerator

Tags: limits

I have come across this function
$$
f(t) = \frac{1+\sin(\frac{1}{1-t})}{(1-t)^3}, \quad t \in \; (0,1).
$$
I could like to know what is the limit of this function as $t$ approaches $1$ from below? Does it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(1-\frac 1 {\frac {\pi} 2+2n \pi}) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

There is a similar sequence of points $t_n$ increasing to $1$ such that $f(t_n)=0$ for all $n$. Can you find it?

Comment: Thanks, I guess you mean $t_n = 1-\frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}\pi + 2n \pi}$. I guess it means that the limit of $f$ does not exist?

Comment: @J.Goles You are right. Your choice of $t_n$ is corect and the conclusion is also correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!